# pandas: multiple conditions while indexing data frame - unexpected behavior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, boolean-logic

I am filtering rows in a dataframe by values in two columns.

For some reason the OR operator behaves like I would expect AND operator to behave and vice versa.

My test code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5), 'b': range(5) })

# let's insert some -1 values
df['a'][1] = -1
df['b'][1] = -1
df['a'][3] = -1
df['b'][4] = -1

df1 = df[(df.a != -1) & (df.b != -1)]
df2 = df[(df.a != -1) | (df.b != -1)]

print(pd.concat([df, df1, df2], axis=1,
                keys = [ 'original df', 'using AND (&)', 'using OR (|)',]))
```

And the result:

```
      original df      using AND (&)      using OR (|)    
             a  b              a   b             a   b
0            0  0              0   0             0   0
1           -1 -1            NaN NaN           NaN NaN
2            2  2              2   2             2   2
3           -1  3            NaN NaN            -1   3
4            4 -1            NaN NaN             4  -1

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

As you can see, the `AND` operator drops every row in which at least one value equals `-1`. On the other hand, the `OR` operator requires both values to be equal to `-1` to drop them. I would expect exactly the opposite result. Could anyone explain this behavior?

I am using pandas 0.13.1.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

> As you can see, the AND operator drops every row in which at least one
>   value equals -1. On the other hand, the OR operator requires both
>   values to be equal to -1 to drop them.

That's right.  Remember that you're writing the condition in terms of what you want to *keep*, not in terms of what you want to drop.  For `df1`:

```
df1 = df[(df.a != -1) & (df.b != -1)]
```

You're saying "keep the rows in which `df.a` isn't -1 and `df.b` isn't -1", which is the same as dropping every row in which at least one value is -1.

For `df2`:

```
df2 = df[(df.a != -1) | (df.b != -1)]
```

You're saying "keep the rows in which either `df.a` or `df.b` is not -1", which is the same as dropping rows where both values are -1.

PS: chained access like `df['a'][1] = -1` can get you into trouble.  It's better to get into the habit of using `.loc` and `.iloc`.

Answer (score 78):

Late answer, but you can also use [query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), e.g. :

```
df_filtered = df.query('a == 4 & b != 2')
```

Answer (score 23):

A little **mathematical logic theory** here:

*"NOT a AND NOT b"* is the same as *"NOT (a OR b)"*, so:

*"a NOT -1 AND b NOT -1"*  is equivalent of  *"NOT (a is -1 OR b is -1)"*, which is opposite (Complement) of *"(a is -1 OR b is -1)"*.

So if you want exact opposite result, df1 and df2 should be as below:

```
df1 = df[(df.a != -1) & (df.b != -1)]
df2 = df[(df.a == -1) | (df.b == -1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
df1 = df[(df['a'] != -1) & (df['b'] != -1)]
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22591267/18145256).

Comment: You've re-posted one line of the accepted solution 2 years later. Please don't do that - it doesn't add anything to the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use parenthesis

If you arrived at this page because the filtering operation didn't give the correct answer even though the conditions are logically correct, then the first thing to check is whether you used parenthesis to separate conditions.

For example, if you wanted to filter out rows where the values in columns `'a'` and `'b'` are not equal to -1, then writing the following code

```py
df[df['a'] != -1 & df['b'] != -1]      # <--- forgot parenthesis
```

would produce a completely unexpected output simply because `&`/`|` have higher precedence than comparison operators like `!=`/`==` etc. You can get the correct output by evaluating each condition separately via parentheses:

```py
df[(df['a'] != -1) & (df['b'] != -1)]  # <--- used parentheses
```

N.B. [@Pedro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40834052/19123103) which uses `query()` eliminates this need because in the numerical expression evaluated in `query`, comparison operators are in fact evaluated before `and`/`or` etc.

---

#### Writing correct logical expressions

By [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), (i) the negation of a union is the intersection of the negations, and (ii) the negation of an intersection is the union of the negations, i.e.,

```
A AND B <=> not A OR not B
A OR B  <=> not A AND not B
```

If the aim is to

> drop every row in which at least one value equals -1

you can either use `AND` operator to identify the rows to **keep** or use `OR` operator to identify the rows to **drop**.

```py
# select rows where both a and b values are not equal to -1
df2_0 = df[df['a'].ne(-1) & df['b'].ne(-1)]

# index of rows where at least one of a or b equals -1
idx = df.index[df.eval('a == -1 or b == -1')]
# drop `idx` rows
df2_1 = df.drop(idx)

df2_0.equals(df2_1) # True
```

On the other hand, if the aim is to

> drop every row in which both values equal -1

you do the exact opposite; either use `OR` operator to identify the rows to **keep** or use `AND` operator to identify the rows to **drop**.