# Pandas apply ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambigous

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new feature using

```
df_transactions['emome'] = df_transactions['emome'].apply(lambda x: 1 if df_transactions['plan_list_price'] ==0 & df_transactions['actual_amount_paid'] > 0 else 0).astype(int)
```

But it raises error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I create a new column that returns 1 when plan_list_price is 0 and actual_amount_paid is >0 else 0?

**I would like to still use pandas apply.**

Comment: "I would like to still use pandas apply." why?

Comment: Because I've met this problem few times before and I want to learn the proper way of using pandas apply.

Comment: The proper way of using apply... is to not use it at all ;) 
Also, the reason is because you used & when you should have used `and`. Don't use them interchangeably. `&` is logical AND _only_ in the context of dataframes.

Comment: The problem is not apply per se. It is your misconception on how to use multiple logical conditions, for which there is a duplicate.

Comment: I tried using    and, it still return the same error

Comment: dupliacte? where?

Comment: It's not a 1:1 duplicate... but here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior

Comment: Take note that in this statement:`df_transactions['plan_list_price'] ==0 & df_transactions['actual_amount_paid'] > 0`, the order of operator is such that python will evaluate it this way: `(df_transactions['plan_list_price'] ==0 & df_transactions['actual_amount_paid']) > 0` which is what gives you the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are really close, but much better is vectorized solution without `apply` - get boolean mask and convert to `int`:

```
mask = (df_transactions['plan_list_price'] == 0) & 
       (df_transactions['actual_amount_paid'] > 0)
df_transactions['emome'] = mask.astype(int)
```

If really want slowier `apply`:

```
f = lambda x: 1 if x['plan_list_price'] ==0 and x['actual_amount_paid'] > 0 else 0
df_transactions['emome'] = df_transactions.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Sample:

```
df_transactions = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                                'plan_list_price':[0,0,0,5,5,0],
                                'actual_amount_paid':[-1,0,9,4,2,3]})


mask = (df_transactions['plan_list_price'] == 0) & \
       (df_transactions['actual_amount_paid'] > 0)
df_transactions['emome1'] = mask.astype(int)

f = lambda x: 1 if x['plan_list_price'] ==0 and x['actual_amount_paid'] > 0 else 0
df_transactions['emome2'] = df_transactions.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df_transactions)

   A  actual_amount_paid  plan_list_price  emome1  emome2
0  a                  -1                0       0       0
1  b                   0                0       0       0
2  c                   9                0       1       1
3  d                   4                5       0       0
4  e                   2                5       0       0
5  f                   3                0       1       1
```

**Timings**:

```
#[60000 rows]
df_transactions = pd.concat([df_transactions] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [201]: %timeit df_transactions['emome1'] = ((df_transactions['plan_list_price'] == 0) & (df_transactions['actual_amount_paid'] > 0)).astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 971 µs per loop

In [202]: %timeit df_transactions['emome2'] = df_transactions.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['plan_list_price'] ==0 and x['actual_amount_paid'] > 0 else 0, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop
```

Comment: I would like to use df_transactions['emome'] = df_transactions['emome'].apply(xxx), how can i fill in the xxx part?

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- On the right side of the equation, the new field (emome)is not
  created yet.
- The lambda function is on x, not on df_transactions, which does not exist in this scope.
- You need to specify axis since you are applying to each row (default is to each column).

From Doc:

> axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0 Axis along which the
>   function is applied:
>
> 0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column. 1 or ‘columns’: apply
>   function to each row.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html