# Drop rows on multiple conditions in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My df has 3 columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1": (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), 
                   "col_2": (0.0, 0.24, 1.0, 0.0, 0.22, 3.11, 0.0),
                    "col_3": ("Mon", "Tue", "Thu", "Fri", "Mon", "Tue", "Thu")})
```

I want to drop rows where df.col_1 is 1.0 and df.col_2 is 0.0. So, I would get:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1": (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), 
                   "col_2": (0.0, 0.24, 1.0, 0.22, 3.11),
                    "col_3": ("Mon", "Tue", "Thu", "Mon", "Tue")})
```

I tried:

```
df_new = df.drop[df[(df['col_1'] == 1.0) & (df['col_2'] == 0.0)].index]
```

It gives me the error:

```
'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Any idea how to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) is a method, you are calling it using `[]`, that is why it gives you:

```
'method' object is not subscriptable
```

change to `()` (a normal method call) and it should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1": (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                   "col_2": (0.0, 0.24, 1.0, 0.0, 0.22, 3.11, 0.0),
                   "col_3": ("Mon", "Tue", "Thu", "Fri", "Mon", "Tue", "Thu")})

df_new = df.drop(df[(df['col_1'] == 1.0) & (df['col_2'] == 0.0)].index)
print(df_new)
```

**Output**

```
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0    0.0   0.00   Mon
1    0.0   0.24   Tue
2    1.0   1.00   Thu
4    0.0   0.22   Mon
5    1.0   3.11   Tue
```

Comment: Just to complement this answer: `&` is the logical `AND` operator, `|` is the logical `OR` and `~` is the logical `NOT`

Comment: Why was the .index method needed at the end? I see that it doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 19):

Try to filter your df with loc. It's so powerful!
The "~" means you want to keep those with the opposite of your condition.
The ":" means you want to keep all the columns

```
df = df.loc[~((df['col_1'] == 1.0) & (df['col_2'] == 0.0)),:]
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use or (|) operator for this ,
Refer this link for it [pandas: multiple conditions while indexing data frame - unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior)

i.e dropping rows where both conditions are met

```
 df = df.loc[~((df['col_1']==1) | (df['col_2']==0))]
```

Comment: The "|" operator is for "OR", while the "&" operator is for "AND" conditions. I think what is needed here is the & operator

Answer (score 9):

```
mask = df['Product_Code'].isin(['filter1', 'filter2', 'filter3'])
df = df[~mask]
df.head()
```

[`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) allows you to filter the entire dataframe based on multiple values in a series. This is the least amount of code to write, compared to other solutions that I know of.

Adding the `~` inside the column wise filter reverses the logic of `isin()`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the location of row which you want remove at "location".

```py
df = df.drop(['location' axix=1, inplace=True]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) here:

```
In [4]: df.query('~(col_1 == 1 & col_2 == 0)')
Out[4]: 
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0    0.0   0.00   Mon
1    0.0   0.24   Tue
2    1.0   1.00   Thu
4    0.0   0.22   Mon
5    1.0   3.11   Tue
```

With `~` the query is negated, returning those observations where the condition `col_1 == 1 & col_2 == 0` does not hold.