# How to delete multiple rows in a pandas DataFrame based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know how to delete rows and columns from a dataframe using `.drop()` method, by passing axis and labels.

Here's the **Dataframe**:

[image]

Now, if i want to remove all rows whose `STNAME` is equal to from (`Arizona` all the way to `Colorado`), how should i do it ?

I know i could just do it by passing row labels 2 to 7 to `.drop()` method but if i have a lot of data and i don't know the starting and ending indexes, it won't be possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456874/drop-rows-on-multiple-conditions-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: You mean that in this case, all rows where STNAME = Arizona, California and Colorado should be deleted? And if you'd give it Arizona and Georgia, every row with STNAME between Arizona and Georgia should be deleted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop rows on multiple conditions in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456874/drop-rows-on-multiple-conditions-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Might be kinda hacky, but here is an option:

```
index1 = df.index[df['STNAME'] == 'Arizona'].tolist()[0]
index2 = df.index[df['STNAME'] == 'Colorado'].tolist()[-1:][0]

df = df.drop(np.arange(index1, index2+1))
```

This basically takes the first index number of Arizona and the last index number of Colorado, and deletes every row from the data frame between these indexes.