# Drop rows from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I am attempting to drop rows from my dataframe that do meet a set of conditions. However it doesn't seem to be working.

Below are the two version which I have tried so far without success:

**Attempt 1**

```
df = df.drop(df[(df['Factorization'] != 0.5) & (df['Value'] != 30) & (df['Total'] == None)].index)
```

**Attempt 2**

```
df.drop(df[(df['Factorization'] != 0.5) & (df['Value'] != 20) & (df['Total'] == None)].index, inplace = True)
```

Please can someone point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please provide an example which is reproducible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop rows on multiple conditions in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456874/drop-rows-on-multiple-conditions-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: I don'y actually get an error. I run print(len(df.index)) to check the number of rows after the code and it is there I notice that the rows number has remained the same as before running df.drop

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456874/drop-rows-on-multiple-conditions-in-pandas-dataframe this confirmed that my attempts should work in theory. However, I have found that the problem lies here.. (df['Total'] == None). When removed I get row number changes. However, I now need to figure out why (df['Total'] == None) prevents any rows from being dropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go around it is by not using drop by, but instead redefining the df to exclude those conditions by adding ~ ahead of the df

```
df = df[~((df['Factorization'] != 0.5) & (df['Value'] != 30) & (df['Total'] == None)]))
```

I may or may not be using one too many () in the code. Please give it a try

Comment: df = df[~(df['Factorization'] != 0.5) & (df['Value'] > 10) & (df['Total'] != None)]
Great help thanks. Adding ~ ahead of the df seems to have done the trick

Comment: i'm glad. Would appreciate if you accept it as a solution