# How should I select which rows I erase in Pandas DataFrame with two conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I need remove some rows for a DataFrame like this:

`import pandas as pd`
`import numpy as np`

`input_ = pd.DataFrame()`
`input_ ['ID'] = [1,     2, 3, 4,   1, 2,   3, 4,   1,   2,   3,   4]`
`input_ ['ST'] = [1,     1, 1, 1,   2, 2,   2, 2,   3,   3,   3,   3]`
`input_ ['V']  = [NaN, NaN, 1, 1, NaN, 1, Nan, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]`\

And finish with a DataFrame like this one:

`output_ ['ID'] = [  2, 3, 4, 2,   3, 4,   2,   3,   4]`
`output_ ['ST'] = [  1, 1, 1, 2,   2, 2,   3,   3,   3]`
`output_ ['V']  = [NaN, 1, 1, 1, Nan, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN]`

Where, I had removed the rows with *ID == 1*, because, this rows have the column *V == float(NaN) [np.isnan(V)]* for **ALL** values in the column *ST*. How should I selec which rows I erase in Pandas DataFrame with this two conditions?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop rows on multiple conditions in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456874/drop-rows-on-multiple-conditions-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: following up the approach on the link above you can try something like this: `input_.drop(input_[(input_['ID']==1) & (input_['V'].isna())].index)`

Comment: @RishabhKumar you seem to misunderstand the question. OP wants to drop `ID=1` because all `V` with that `ID` are `nan`.

Comment: @QuangHoang okay got it, it gave the same output, so didn't read the question carefully

Comment: I'm a bit confused because he says 'with this two conditions' and a different data set might not get the same results for 1 or 2 conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby().transform('any')` to check if the group contains some `notna`:

```
valids = input_.V.notna().groupby(input_.ID).transform('any')

output = input_[valids]
```

Output:

```
    ID  ST    V
1    2   1  NaN
2    3   1  1.0
3    4   1  1.0
5    2   2  1.0
6    3   2  NaN
7    4   2  1.0
9    2   3  NaN
10   3   3  NaN
11   4   3  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input_ = input_[(input_['ID']!=1) & input_['V'].notnull()]
```

I'm not sure I fully understand your question and whether you wanted to filter by 1, or if you only did that to get rid of the NaN values. If you don't want to actually filter by ID==1, just do:

```
input_ = input_[input_['V'].notnull()]
```

Output for both:

```
   ID  ST    V
2   3   1  1.0
3   4   1  1.0
5   2   2  1.0
7   4   2  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_ = pd.DataFrame()

input_ ['ID'] = [1,     2, 3, 4,   1, 2,   3, 4,   1,   2,   3,   4]

input_ ['ST'] = [1,     1, 1, 1,   2, 2,   2, 2,   3,   3,   3,   3]

input_ ['V']  = ['NaN', 'NaN', 1, 1, 'NaN', 1,'Nan', 1, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN']

input_1 = pd.DataFrame(input_)

print(input_1)

input_1.drop(0, inplace = True)
input_1.drop(4, inplace = True)
input_1.drop(8, inplace = True)

print(input_1)
```