# Drop rows with multiple specific values in python csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

I'm working on a dataframe and I want to drop some rows with multiple specific string value on column.
For example, the df is like this:

```
 ID     type           price
da499   hotel         $41946
fa987   hotel         $251
gh552   Restaurant    $764
vc947   bar           $2314
bc521   bar           $2191
fv231   Restaurant    $4985
df987   estate        $654
bv231   estate        $231
kc818   school        $91456
```

And I want to drop the rows with `type` equal to hotel, Restaurant and estate to form a df like this:

```
 ID     type           price
vc947   bar           $2314
bc521   bar           $2191
kc818   school        $91456
```

How can I use the `drop` function to get the result?

Comment: `df[~df['type'].isin(['hotel','Restaurant','estate'])]`?

Comment: does this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456874/drop-rows-on-multiple-conditions-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method to get the row where `type` is equal to `'hotel'`, `'Restaurant'` or `'estate'`. Then you can reverse the boolean filter with `~`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df = df[~df['type'].isin(['hotel', 'Restaurant', 'estate'])]
```

```
          ID    type   price
    3  vc947     bar   $2314
    4  bc521     bar   $2191
    8  kc818  school  $91456
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) method, you can do:

```
df = df.drop(df.index[df['type'].isin(['hotel', 'Restaurant', 'estate'])])
```

```
          ID    type   price
    3  vc947     bar   $2314
    4  bc521     bar   $2191
    8  kc818  school  $91456
```

Although, for performance reason, the **former is faster**.