# In Python Pandas, how to search if column elements contains the first 2 digits

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to Python and currently I am trying to build a function that searches for the first 2 digits of the elements in a column and if true, return the result with a new header such as region

For example,

```
   Adres  AreaCode Region
0  SArea    123191      A
1  BArea    122929      A
2  AArea    132222      B
```

I want the function to search for just the first 2 digits of the AreaCode which would give me the result of along with a new header of Region which classifies the Region based on the first 2 digits of the AreaCode.
So in this case 12 would give me A and 13 would give me B

I already tried this

```
df.loc[df.AreaCode == 123191, 'Region'] = 'A'
```

and this worked for the entire AreaCode but I have no idea how to modify it so that I would be able to search based on the first 2 digits.

and I tried this

```
df.loc[df.AreaCode.str.contains == 12, 'Region' ] = 'A'
```

but it gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values,
                which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

How do I fix this and thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried this df.loc[df.AreaCode.str.contains == 12, 'Region' ] = 'A'
>   but it gives me the error: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

You could simply convert it to a string, then use the same code:

```
df.loc[df.AreaCode.astype(str).str.startswith('12'), 'Region' ] = 'A'
```

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped!

Comment: @w-m Can you elaborate why astype is required here as without that explicit conversion I got an error

Comment: @mad_: Look at the `AttributeError` already noted in the question. The `.str` accessor can only be used on columns that already hold strings. `AreaCode` was represented with ints in this case. Thus they have to be converted to strings first.

Comment: @w-m is it possible to add another condition such as df.loc[df.AreaCode.astype(str).str.startswith('12' or '13'), 'Region' ] = 'A'     Thanks!

Comment: @Gary sure. Use `|` as or: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22591267/463796. You'll have to repeat the whole query though, can't put the or just between the values: `df.loc[...startswith('12') | ...startswith('13'), ...]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df.loc[df.AreaCode.astype(str).str.startswith("12") == True, 'Region' ]
```

The line below will give you a series with True/False for each row and what becomes the filter for the dataframe.

```
df.AreaCode.astype(str).str.startswith("12")
```

Assigning a equals test makes it a filter.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps -

First convert Area code column dtype to string with

```
df.AreaCode = df.AreaCode.astype(str)
```

And then do filtering with first characters of the column

**`df.loc[(df.AreaCode.str.startswith('12')) &  (df.Region=='A')]`**

Answer (score 1):

This will work I guess.

> df.loc[df.AreaCode.str.startswith('12'), 'Region' ] = 'A'

Comment: This still gives me the error which i think because it isn't a string.w-m's answer solved it for me. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First convert the data type to `str` like this

```
df.AreaCode = df.AreaCode.astype('str')
```

Then check for the number in beginning like this

```
df.loc[df.AreaCode.startswith('12'), 'Region' ] = 'A'
```

Assuming you need nan in the rows which dont start with A, you can do a map like this

```
df['Region'] = df['AreaCode'].map(lambda x : 'A' if x.startswith('12') else np.nan )
```