# Data choosing based on several condition (code improve)

Tags: pandas

```
df= df[df.a< 7.8]
df= df[df.a> 7.50]
df= df[df.b> 44.85]
```

Can this code be written in one line? Or shorter than 3 lines?

Comment: It [has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior) in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with chain `&` for bitwise `AND` or `|` for bitwise `OR` with another condition:

```
df1 = df[df.a.between(7.5, 7.8, inclusive=False) & (df.b> 44.85)]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[(df.a > 7.5) & (df.a < 7.8) & (df.b> 44.85)]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[7.6,7.5,7.4,7.56,5,7.7],
         'b':[57,48,59,44,42,53],

})

df1 = df[df.a.between(7.5, 7.8, inclusive=False) & (df.b> 44.85)]
print (df1)
     a   b
0  7.6  57
5  7.7  53
```

Comment: `inclusive=False` is needed. I was slower due to double-checking that.

Answer (score 4):

I will using `query`

```
df.query('a > 7.5 and a < 7.8 and b > 44.85')
```