# Filtering rows by multiple conditions - why isn't this working?

Tags: python, pandas

I've checked answers to similar questions, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22591267/11222963) and still can't get this filter to work. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find it.

```
print(customers[['GUID','address_type']].head())

                                   GUID      address_type
0  4c07d11e-2d5c-851d-e053-ca3ca8c0ca7f     StreetAddress
1  4c07d11e-3bac-851d-e053-ca3ca8c0ca7f  StreetAddressExt
2                                   NaN               NaN
3  4c07d11e-2d5c-851d-e053-ca3ca8c0ca7f     StreetAddress
4                                   NaN               NaN
```

I want to filter out the rows where `GUID` is `nan` and then a couple of `address_types`.

```
mask = (customers['GUID'].notnull()) | (customers['address_type']!='POI') | (customers['address_type']!='locality')

customers = customers[mask].copy()
```

Now let's check the result:

```
print(customers[['GUID','address_type']].head())

                                   GUID      address_type
0  4c07d11e-2d5c-851d-e053-ca3ca8c0ca7f     StreetAddress
1  4c07d11e-3bac-851d-e053-ca3ca8c0ca7f  StreetAddressExt
2                                   NaN               NaN
3  4c07d11e-2d5c-851d-e053-ca3ca8c0ca7f     StreetAddress
4                                   NaN               NaN
```

I still have `nan` in `GUID` ... what's happening here? If I set a simple filter of just `customers['GUID'].notnull())` it works. But combining conditions does nothing. Any ideas?

This is literally all of my code so far (I have added jezrels extra `!='NaN`), nothing crazy happening in the background:

```
import pandas as pd

customers = pd.read_csv('data\latest_geocoded.csv',low_memory=False)

customers[['GUID','address_type']].head()

mask = (customers['GUID'].notnull()) | (customers['GUID']!='NaN') | (customers['address_type']!='POI') | (customers['address_type']!='locality')

customers = customers[mask].copy()

print(customers[['GUID','address_type']].head())

                                   GUID      address_type
0  4c07d11e-2d5c-851d-e053-ca3ca8c0ca7f     StreetAddress
1  4c07d11e-3bac-851d-e053-ca3ca8c0ca7f  StreetAddressExt
2                                   NaN               NaN
3  4c07d11e-2d5c-851d-e053-ca3ca8c0ca7f     StreetAddress
4                                   NaN               NaN
```

Comment: Have you checked what happens if you apply filters in sequence instead of all together?

Comment: It works fine in sequence. I can do that. But this is still puzzling me. I've done this multiple condition filtering many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retain the customers that **don't** have:

1. a null value for 'GUID'

or

2. an address type in {'POI', 'locality'}

I think it would be sufficient to change the *or* operators to *and* operators, i.e:

```
mask = (customers['GUID'].notnull()) & (customers['address_type']!='POI') & (customers['address_type']!='locality')
```

Currently, in row 2 of your example, the address type is `NaN`, which is not equal to 'POI', and therefore the row is not dropped.