# How to slice pandas dataframe with interger value as column name

Tags: python, dataframe

Iam working with dataset with year as the column name. Is there way to slice it.

here below is the example. I want to slice dataframe with customer count 0.

`df.loc[df.2020==0,:]` this yields error.

```
Department      2016    2017    2018    2019    2020
Electronics     2030    1029    1839    893     20
Babyshop        2030    1029    1839    893     0
Grocery         2030    1029    1839    893     2
Hardware        2030    1029    1839    893     10
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Department      2016    2017    2018    2019    2020
Electronics     2030    1029    1839    893     20
Babyshop        2030    1029    1839    893     0
Grocery         2030    1029    1839    893     2
Hardware        2030    1029    1839    893     10
"""), sep='\s+')

print(df[df['2020'] == 0])
```

Output:

```
  Department  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020
1   Babyshop  2030  1029  1839   893     0
```

If you want to look for rows with 0 customers in more than 1 year, you can club them with an or condition like this:

```py
print(df[(df['2019'] == 0) | (df['2020'] == 0)])
```

Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior) with more on selecting rows based on multiple conditions.

Comment: This gives the fix, but fails to explain the error. You should say that `df.col` is a shortcut for `df['col']` that is only valid when `col` looks like an identifier (starts with a letter, does not contain spaces, ...), and does not clash with other attributes like `index`, `T`, etc.

Comment: @ganeshghimire you now have the full code for reference

Comment: df2[df2.2020== 0.0]   File "<ipython-input-23-8e7b91a4439e>", line 1
    df2[df2.2020== 0.0]
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: 2020 does not start with an alphabet