# Filter over two columns on the pandas dataframe, where one represents the time of phone calls

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as following below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DAY_OF_WEEK': ['Monday', 'Sunday', 'Saturday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday'],
                   'HOUR': ['21:02:02', '11:22:02', '23:02:02', '09:22:02', '09:02:02'],
              'id': [1,2,2,3,1]})

df
```

I need to applicate a filter for that a new dataframe have only register where `HOUR` between 19:00:00 and 07:00:00 or `DAY_OF_WEEK` == 'Sunday'. An expected output:

```
DAY_OF_WEEK |   HOUR  | ID
Monday      |21:02:02 | 1
Saturday    |23:02:02 | 2
Monday      |09:22:02 | 3
```

I trying the following:

```
df2 = df.loc[(pd.to_timedelta(df.HOUR).between('06:00:00','19:00:00') | df['DAY_OF_WEEK'] == 'Sunday')]
calls_night_or_sunday = df[~df2].copy()
```

but, I have an output where all the lines received `NaN`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.loc[('19' < df['HOUR']) | (df['HOUR'] < '06') |  (df['DAY_OF_WEEK'] == 'Sunday')]
```

Output:

```
  DAY_OF_WEEK      HOUR  id
0      Monday  21:02:02   1
1      Sunday  11:22:02   2
2    Saturday  23:02:02   2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DAY_OF_WEEK': ['Monday', 'Sunday', 'Saturday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday'],
                   'HOUR': ['21:02:02', '11:22:02', '23:02:02', '09:22:02', '09:02:02'],
              'id': [1,2,2,3,1]})

df2 = df[(df.HOUR.between('19:00:00','23:59:59')) | (df.HOUR.between('00:00:00','06:00:00')) | (df.DAY_OF_WEEK == 'Sunday')]
df2

# Output
# DAY_OF_WEEK   HOUR    id
# 0 Monday  21:02:02    1
# 1 Sunday  11:22:02    2
# 2 Saturday    23:02:02    2
```

[Pandas conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior)

UPDATED:
timeranges changed

Comment: lines #3 and #4 bring time values ​​out of range

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You wrote "where HOUR between 19:00:00 and 07:00:00 or DAY_OF_WEEK == 'Sunday'" and in example wrote "Monday      |09:22:02 | 3". 09:22:02 not in between 19:00:00 and 07:00:00.

Answer (score -1):

Try using  "|" instead of "or"

Comment: Try using .query() --- df2=df.query('(HOUR >="06:00:00" and HOUR<="19:00:00") or Day_of_week == "Sunday")

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

```
df2 = df.loc[(pd.to_timedelta(df.HOUR).between('06:00:00','19:00:00') | (df['DAY_OF_WEEK'] == 'Sunday'))]
```

Comment: between 19:00:00 and 07:00:00

Comment: In this way all data receives NaN