# Drop rows by multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I know i can make a new df while dropping by criterias:
 `df = df[df.ID != 0]`

But what if i want to use more criterias. I want to take out all rows that satisfy condition A and B. An example:

```
        for v in range(len(drop)-1):
            df = df[df.town != drop.at[v, 0] and df.state != drop.at[v, 1]]
```

drop is just a df with the names of towns and states, which should drop if in one row bot conditions are true.

I get this Error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior)

Comment: got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas require you to split your conditions into boolean vectors, then merge them with a boolean operator (`&`, `|` and not `and`, `or`)

This should fix your problem :

```py
df = df[(df.town != drop.at[v, 0]) & (df.state != drop.at[v, 1])]
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: Thanks for youre answeres. Can it be, that this will drop all rows with criteria 1 and criteria 2? I want to drop the rows only, if criteria 1 and criteria 2 are true for the same row.

Comment: got it, thanks all. i used the wrong operator.

Comment: Here the `&` means both conditions, for a row, needs to be validated. If you use `|` any of the conditions will be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

FYI, [Logical operators for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas).

---

Try this:

```py
criteria_1 = df.town != drop.at[v, 0]
criteria_2 = df.state != drop.at[v, 1]

criteria = criteria_1 & criteria_2

df_db = df_db[criteria]
```

Comment: Thanks for youre answeres. Can it be, that this will drop all rows with criteria 1 and criteria 2? I want to drop the rows only, if criteria 1 and criteria 2 are true for the same row.

Comment: got it, thanks all. i used the wrong operator.