# How to copy a field based on a condition of another column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to copy a column's field into a variable, based on a specific condition, and then delete it.

This dataframe contains data of some kids, that have their favourite toy and colour associated:

```
data = {'Kid': ['Richard', 'Daphne', 'Andy', 'May', 'Claire', 'Mozart', 'Jane'],
        'Toy':  ['Ball', 'Doll', 'Car', 'Barbie', 'Frog', 'Bear', 'Doll'],
        'Colour': ['white', np.nan, 'red', 'pink', 'green', np.nan, np.nan]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Kid', 'Toy','Colour'])

print (df)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
       Kid       Toy Colour
0  Richard      Ball  white
1   Daphne      Doll    NaN
2     Andy       Car    red
3      May    Barbie   pink
4   Claire      Frog  green
5   Mozart      Bear    NaN
6     Jane      Doll    NaN
```

The condition is: If a kid does have a toy, but it does not have a colour, then save both the kid and the toy in a separate array as follows and maintain the order/matching:

```
toy_array = ["Doll", "Bear", "Doll"]
kid_array = ["Daphne", "Mozart", "Jane"]
```

And then delete the toy from the dataframe. So the final dataframe should look like this:

```
       Kid     Toy Colour
0  Richard    Ball  white
1   Daphne     NaN    NaN
2     Andy     Car    red
3      May  Barbie   pink
4   Claire    Frog  green
5   Mozart     NaN    NaN
6     Jane     NaN    NaN
```

I got inspired by many sources, along with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22591174/15504461), and I tried this:

```
kid_array.append(df.loc[(df['Toy'] != np.nan) & (df['Colour'] == np.nan)])
print(kid_array)
```

I am at the very beginning, I highly appreciate all your help if you could possibly help me!

Comment: Wau, so nice question - input data sample, ouput data sample, your code what you try. Super! Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much, @jezrael ! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test missing and no misisng values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and
[`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and then set missing values to `Toy` column by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = df['Toy'].notna() & df['Colour'].isna()

df.loc[mask, 'Toy'] = np.nan
```

Or in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Toy'] = df['Toy'].mask(mask)
```

Or by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Toy'] = np.where(mask, np.nan, df['Toy'])
```

---

```
print (df)
       Kid     Toy Colour
0  Richard    Ball  white
1   Daphne     NaN    NaN
2     Andy     Car    red
3      May  Barbie   pink
4   Claire    Frog  green
5   Mozart     NaN    NaN
6     Jane     NaN    NaN
```

If need lists:

```
toy_array = df.loc[mask, 'Toy'].tolist()
kid_array = df.loc[mask, 'Kid'].tolist()

print (toy_array)
['Doll', 'Bear', 'Doll']

print (kid_array)
['Daphne', 'Mozart', 'Jane']
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I learned so much from your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct, just the function to compare needs to be matched with the correct function used for comparison in Numpy Library

```
numpy.isnan()
```

Try the following code

```
kid_array.append(df.loc[(!numpy.isnan( df['Toy'])) & (!numpy.isnan(df['Colour']))])
```