# pandas dataframe multiple condition error with "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous"

Tags: pandas, dataframe

pandas version: `'1.2.3'`, python version: 3.7.9

code:

```
   x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[2,3]})
   x['a']>1 & x['b'] <= 2
```

it shows `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

this kind of usage seems common.
[pandas: multiple conditions while indexing data frame - unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior)

thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If check linked answer difference is missing parentheses, because priority of operators, so add them:

```
mask = (x['a']>1) & (x['b'] <= 2)

df = x[mask]
```