# List Comprehensions in dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

Let us assume, I have data in dataframe which contains 3 variables as follows

```
        t                   a             b        
2012-03-01 00:00:00        100             2
2012-03-01 00:00:10        200            5.6
2012-03-01 00:00:20        500            6.2
2012-03-01 00:00:30        600            7.0
2012-03-01 00:00:40         50            3.2
2012-03-01 00:00:50         70           12.12
2012-03-01 01:00:00       1000           15.14
2012-03-01 00:00:10       2100            4.9
```

What I would like to do is filter the datasets if `100 < a < 2000` and `b > 5` and save those values to new dataframe. So at the end hoping to get new dataframe table like this:

```
       t                    a              b               
2012-03-01 00:00:10        200            5.6
2012-03-01 00:00:20        500            6.2
2012-03-01 00:00:30        600            7.0
2012-03-01 01:00:00       1000           15.14
```

Can somebody help me on this problem where more conditional statement can be applied for problem such as mine in list comprehension?

Comment: I think you can use the answers to this questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior

Comment: Now `a` and `b` are clear and the conditions. But showing what you tried and where you got stuck is nevertheless useful.

Comment: I thought this makes reader confused hence removed it.  would be glad if you can help me. :)

Comment: another point: are you maybe talking of [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of *list compression*?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Basically, I am looking a way how this can be solved by list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing the initial approach in [of Syed Hussain (rev #2 of answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68390430/2), your feedback and the enlightening [answer to another question by Nipun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897625/2932052), I'm sure that a filtered dataframe has to be retrieved like this:

```
filtered_df = df[(100 < df.a) & (df.a < 2000) & (df.b > 5)].copy()
```

That is, enclose every single of your original filter conditions on fields `a` and `b` into parentheses and combine them with the binary *and* operator (`&`). This way `100 < df.a < 2000` has to be split into `100 < df.a` and `df.a < 2000` (which is, BTW, exactly the way Python interprets [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)).

I think that [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) would not be the right tool here, because (as can be read in the [first revision of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68390296/1)) you are interested in a result in form of another dataframe. So filtering a given dataframe would be the most efficient way to do it.

The `copy()` at the end is done for preserving your original data, please see [*why should I make a copy of a data frame in pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27673231/2932052) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

you mean something like this :

```
newdf = df[(100 < df.a) & (df.a < 2000) & (df.b > 5)]
```

you can check out this [link](https://www.listendata.com/2019/07/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe.html) for more ways to do this.

By using List Comprehension I guess you mean something like this:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame((row[0],row[1],row[2]) for row in df.itertuples() if (100<int(row[1])<2000 and int(row[2])>5 ))
```

Changes suggested by [Wolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2932052/wolf)

Comment: I further clarified my question, please do have a look at it.

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath I have updated my answer. Please let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Why are you using the bitwise and operator here?

Comment: I would add .copy() to the end of this to ensure that any changes made to the new dataframe don't change the original, and avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: This codes is not working when I tested with my datasets. Getting error 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

Comment: @Wolf check out MSeifert answer to understand this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath try using newdf = df.loc[(100<df.a<2000) & (df.b > 5)]

Comment: @SyedHussain thanks for clarification, seems asker turned `&` into `and`?

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath just guessing: maybe `(100 < df.a) & (df.a < 2000) & (df.b > 5)` could work?

Comment: @Wolf No, the asker turned `or` into `|` and `and` into `&`

Comment: @Wolf yes this work. Thanks.  But can we do same using List Comprehensions.

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath from my limited knowledge, List Comprehension is used to get lists as output, in your use-case you want a Dataframe as a final output so I don't think list comprehension would be feasible solution.

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath I have updated my answer to use list comprehension, please check it and tell if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(100 < df.a < 2000) & (df.b > 5)]
```