# Get values from column that meets some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am at the beginning of learning pandas, I have data frame about cars and I want to return the models of car that are automatic and manufactured in the last two years. I am trying to write the code as below:

```
df.loc[((df[['year']].drop_duplicates().nlargest(2, 'year')) && (df.loc[df['Sparetype'] =='Automatic'])) ,'model']
```

But I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Hala\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3412/2229436407.py", line 1
    df.loc[((df[['year']].drop_duplicates().nlargest(2, 'year')) && (df.loc[df['Sparetype'] =='Automatic'])) ,'model']
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I replace `&&` to `&` I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'int'
```

Comment: Replace `&&` by `&`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: multiple conditions while indexing data frame - unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior)

Comment: when i use & instead of && i get other error , this( TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'int')

Answer (score 1):

There is no double ampersand `&&` in python, instead use `and`