# Filtering dataframes in pandas, how to chain multiple filters?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which filters my data, like so:

```
def get_gappers(data):
    data = pd.read_csv(data)
    open =  data['open']
    df = data[(data['change'] >= 10)]
    df = df[(open <= 15)]
    df = df[(open >= 1)]
    display(df)
```

Which gives me the following:

```
date    volume  open    close   high    low previous close  change
214 2022-03-08  88067102.0  13.035  13.51   14.27   12.4401 12.84   11.137072
219 2022-03-15  76398350.0  14.910  15.57   15.80   14.9000 14.25   10.877193
```

My question is how do I do the filtering using a single line? E.g something like:

```
    df = data[(data['change'] >= 10) & open <= 15 open >= 1)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: multiple conditions while indexing data frame - unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = data[(data['change'] >= 10) & (open <= 15) & (open >= 1)]
```

or using `pandas.DataFrame.query`:

```
df = data.query("1 <= open <= 15 and change >= 10")
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between these two?