# I want a subset with more than one filter

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have titanic data set in python. I need to subset three columns with a filter for each. For Instance, I need a data frame of Name, age > 40, and of only class A passengers. Is there any possibility to apply all filters in one command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to import data with those columns whom you want to subset, and then apply filters.

First method

```
titanic = pd.read_excel("titanic.xlsx", usecols= ["Name", "Age", "Pclass"])

titanic_subdata= titanic[(titanic["Pclass"] ==1) & (titanic["Name"]) & (titanic["Age"] > 40)]
```

Second method

```
titanic1 = titanic[["Name", "Sex", "Age"]]
titanic_subdata= titanic1[(titanic1["Pclass"] ==1) & (titanic1["Name"]) & (titanic1["Age"] > 40)]
```